# Constraint rule not working as expected when there is only one planning entity

Tags: optaplanner

I have a simple field mapping use case where I need to intelligently find the target field for an input source field based on multiple constraints.

To make it clear, there is only one source Field and there are say 100 target field. The goal is to find the most matching target field for the input source field based on constraints.

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class FieldMapping {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    public FieldMapping()
    {

    }


    protected Field inputField;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {
            "targetFieldRange" })
    protected Field targetField; 
}  

@PlanningSolution
public class FieldMappingSolution {

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "targetFieldRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<PlanningRecommField> targetFields;

   @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

    private SolverStatus solverStatus;
```

The challenge is on writing the constraint rules. Since there is only 1 source field , there will be only one instance of FieldMapping planning entity. One constraint rule attempted is given below

```java
public   Constraint requiredLeafNode(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {

                return
                constraintFactory.forEachUniquePair(FieldMapping.class,Joiners.equal(FieldMapping::getTargetField)).
                filter((mapping1,mapping2) -> !mapping2.getTargetField().isLeafNode())
                .penalize("Not leaf node", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
      
        }
```

But since there is only 1 fieldmapping instance , the constraint is not working. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the `forEachUniquePair` is used in constraints that impact score based on a relation between pairs of planning entity instances.

I think that what you are trying to achieve could be expressed by a simpler constraint as follows:

```
Constraint requiredLeafNode(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory
        .forEach(FieldMapping.class)
        .filter((mapping) -> !mapping.getTargetField().isLeafNode())
        .penalize("Not leaf node", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
}
```

That said, if you always deal with just a single planning entity instance, OptaPlanner is probably overkill. A rule engine, of just a couple of hard-coded rules, might be the way to go.

Comment: Can you give more insights on how to use rule engine like drools to solve this. I need score based relevant search based on rule condition. When i search for drools with score based calculation , its always getting redirected to Optaplanner.  Also rather than 1 source field, we may have n source field meaning n PlanningEntities . If so, optaplanner is a correct fit  ?

Comment: In general, use OptaPlanner if your search space is too large for a brute-force algorithm (although OptaPlanner supports exhaustive search algorithms too).
If you have a single entity and hundreds of candidates to select from, in my opinion, there is no need to bring any new technology to solve it.